# How to fit a image in non-static size div?

Tags: html, css, web

How to fit a image which size is defined by % in non-static size div? Here is what i did for this moment, photo is commented, to show you how layout look like when it is looking like i want, if you uncomment photo, whole layout will be broken. I want all units to be same type, or similar, and just find the way to fit this photo in div without destroying whole layout.

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <title>Document</title>
    <style>
        *{
            padding: 0;
            margin: 0;
            box-sizing: border-box;
        }

        body{
            width: 100%;
            height: 100vh;
        }

        /* == WHOLE PAGE ==*/
        .landing{
            width: 100%;
            height: 100%;
            display: flex;
            flex-flow: column; 
        }

        /* HEADER */
        .header{
            background: #F582A7;
            flex: 0 1 10%;
            display: flex;
            justify-content: center;
            align-items: center;
        }

        .header > ul{
            display: flex;
            flex-direction: row;
            list-style: none;
        }

        .header > ul > li{
            padding: 0 10px 0 10px;
        }

        /* CONTENT */
        .mainContent{
            background: #F10086;
            flex: 1 1 auto;
            display: flex;
            flex-flow: column-reverse;
        }

        .bottomContent{
            width: 100%;
            height: 50%;
            flex: 1 1 50%;
            text-align: center;
            display: flex;
            flex-direction: column;
            justify-content: center;
        }

        .topContent{
            width: 100%;
            height: 50%;
            flex: 1 1 50%;
        }

        .topContent > img{
            max-height: 100%;
            max-width: 100%;
        }

        /* TABS */
        .tabs{
            background: #711A75;
            flex: 0 1 18%;
            display: flex;
            justify-content: space-around;
            align-items: center;
        }

        .tab{
            height: 80%;
            width: 30%;
            background: #180A0A;
            border-radius: 15px;
        }
    </style>
</head>
<body>
    <div class="landing">
        <div class="header">
            <ul>
                <li>Test 0</li>
                <li>Test 0</li>
                <li>Test 0</li>
            </ul>
        </div>
        <div class="mainContent">
            <div class="bottomContent">
                <h1>Lorem, ipsum dolor.</h1>
                <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Laborum recusandae rem dolorum consectetur repellendus molestiae amet quo reprehenderit possimus eaque.</p>
            </div>
            <div class="topContent">
                <!--<img src="https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/thumb/3/30/Vector-based_example.svg/1024px-Vector-based_example.svg.png" alt="circle">-->
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="tabs">
            <div class="tab"></div>
            <div class="tab"></div>
            <div class="tab"></div>
        </div>
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To cover whole width of the page, use [`object-fit`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/object-fit) (the image height is specified is arbitrary units, `em` in this example.

[That answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/71513268/) does it without `object-fit`, but uses the image as a background instead. That can be used when the image is just “decorational” – you can't have `alt` text on it etc.

Both variants are used in very similar way.

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <title>Document</title>
    <style>
        *{
            padding: 0;
            margin: 0;
            box-sizing: border-box;
        }

        body{
            width: 100%;
            height: 100vh;
        }

        /* == WHOLE PAGE ==*/
        .landing{
            width: 100%;
            height: 100%;
            display: flex;
            flex-flow: column; 
        }

        /* HEADER */
        .header{
            background: #F582A7;
            flex: 0 1 10%;
            display: flex;
            justify-content: center;
            align-items: center;
        }

        .header > ul{
            display: flex;
            flex-direction: row;
            list-style: none;
        }

        .header > ul > li{
            padding: 0 10px 0 10px;
        }

        /* CONTENT */
        .mainContent{
            background: #F10086;
            flex: 1 1 auto;
            display: flex;
            flex-flow: column-reverse;
        }

        .bottomContent{
            width: 100%;
            height: 50%;
            flex: 1 1 50%;
            text-align: center;
            display: flex;
            flex-direction: column;
            justify-content: center;
        }

        .topContent{
            width: 100%;
            height: 50%;
            flex: 1 1 50%;
        }

        .topContent > img{
            max-height: 100%;
            max-width: 100%;
        }

        /* TABS */
        .tabs{
            background: #711A75;
            flex: 0 1 18%;
            display: flex;
            justify-content: space-around;
            align-items: center;
        }

        .tab{
            height: 80%;
            width: 30%;
            background: #180A0A;
            border-radius: 15px;
        }
    </style>
</head>
<body>
    <div class="landing">
        <div class="header">
            <ul>
                <li>Test 0</li>
                <li>Test 0</li>
                <li>Test 0</li>
            </ul>
        </div>
        <div class="mainContent">
            <div class="bottomContent">
                <h1>Lorem, ipsum dolor.</h1>
                <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Laborum recusandae rem dolorum consectetur repellendus molestiae amet quo reprehenderit possimus eaque.</p>
            </div>
            <div class="topContent">
                <img src="https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/thumb/3/30/Vector-based_example.svg/1024px-Vector-based_example.svg.png" alt="circle" style="object-fit: cover; height: 10em; width: 100%">
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="tabs">
            <div class="tab"></div>
            <div class="tab"></div>
            <div class="tab"></div>
        </div>
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

Rather than use an image tag, you may want insert the image as a background using CSS.  Then you can [set the `background-size` property](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/background-size) to something appropriate like `contain` or `cover`.

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <title>Document</title>
    <style>
        *{
            padding: 0;
            margin: 0;
            box-sizing: border-box;
        }

        body{
            width: 100%;
            height: 100vh;
        }

        /* == WHOLE PAGE ==*/
        .landing{
            width: 100%;
            height: 100%;
            display: flex;
            flex-flow: column; 
        }

        /* HEADER */
        .header{
            background: #F582A7;
            flex: 0 1 10%;
            display: flex;
            justify-content: center;
            align-items: center;
        }

        .header > ul{
            display: flex;
            flex-direction: row;
            list-style: none;
        }

        .header > ul > li{
            padding: 0 10px 0 10px;
        }

        /* CONTENT */
        .mainContent{
            background: #F10086;
            flex: 1 1 auto;
            display: flex;
            flex-flow: column-reverse;
        }

        .bottomContent{
            width: 100%;
            height: 50%;
            flex: 1 1 50%;
            text-align: center;
            display: flex;
            flex-direction: column;
            justify-content: center;
        }

        .topContent{
            width: 100%;
            height: 50%;
            flex: 1 1 50%;
            background: url('https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/thumb/3/30/Vector-based_example.svg/1024px-Vector-based_example.svg.png');
            background-repeat: no-repeat;
            background-size: contain;
        }

        .topContent > img{
            max-height: 100%;
            max-width: 100%;
        }

        /* TABS */
        .tabs{
            background: #711A75;
            flex: 0 1 18%;
            display: flex;
            justify-content: space-around;
            align-items: center;
        }

        .tab{
            height: 80%;
            width: 30%;
            background: #180A0A;
            border-radius: 15px;
        }
    </style>
</head>
<body>
    <div class="landing">
        <div class="header">
            <ul>
                <li>Test 0</li>
                <li>Test 0</li>
                <li>Test 0</li>
            </ul>
        </div>
        <div class="mainContent">
            <div class="bottomContent">
                <h1>Lorem, ipsum dolor.</h1>
                <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Laborum recusandae rem dolorum consectetur repellendus molestiae amet quo reprehenderit possimus eaque.</p>
            </div>
            <div class="topContent">
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="tabs">
            <div class="tab"></div>
            <div class="tab"></div>
            <div class="tab"></div>
        </div>
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```